# sudo echo in centos or redhat is not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, password

I am using the following command to skip the '**password**' check using '**echo**' in ubuntu,

```
echo $password | sudo -S apt-get install -y default-jdk
```

I am using the following command to skip the '**password**' check using '**echo**' in centos,

```
echo $password | yum -S -y install python-pip
```

But the **-S** and **echo** is **not working** in **CentOS** rather, It is asking me to enter the password again. What is the way to skip asking for password using echo Or anything wrong in this command?

**NOTE**: I can't use SSH-KEY

**EDITED:**
To make it clear,

1)I need to deliver a script to my customer, where the script will install python-pip as one of the part. The customer will provide the password as input for that script so I don't want the customer to enter the password during the execution of script.

(i.e) I need to install the python-pip in the same machine without asking the user to enter the password. So as I tried in ubuntu I used the echo $password with -S, So I dont have any way to edit the sudoers also.

So now Is there a way like echo $password / -S in centos?

Comment: Are you sure `yum` support `-S`? Why you not use `sudo` for CentOS?

Comment: Could you update me the sample SUDO command form this? If we are not using -S what is the command to skip the password in CentOS?

Comment: @dsstorefile1 Could you give an example with sudo in centos for not to ask for a password Thanks, If you could explain for installing python-pip without a password, It would be Great.

Comment: @dsstorefile1 I edited the question, check the EDITED part, please respond to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t see `-S` in yum’s man page. 
Do you have some reason to believe that it means something?

Maybe you mean `echo $password | sudo -S yum -y install python-pip`?

`echo $password` is bad security. 
Can you set up `/etc/sudoers`
to allow the user to run `apt-get` and `yum` without asking for a password?

Comment: this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you run your entire script with sudo so that everything within runs as root.

For most of the operations you could deescalate to an unprivileged user for performing non-critical tasks like in the form of `sudo -u nobody command`